# Creating a new column with summation of 4 columns

Tags: r, sum

I have a dataset that goes like this:

```
             var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 varTotal

Person A:       5    5    5    5    5    5
        
Person B:       1    2    1    4    7    1

Person C:       0    1    3    2    3    2
```

For now, varTotal is empty, but I want to fill it up with summation of var1 through var4 (no var5 or var6).

Comment: `mydf$varTotal <- rowSums(mydf[1:4])`

Answer (score 0):

We can use dplyr with `rowSums(across(<tidy-select>))`, se we can use the `tidyselect` part to select the columuns to feed to `rowSums`:

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>% mutate(varTotal = rowSums(across(var1:var4)))
```